# hostname invalid when executing "kubeadm alpha certs xxx "

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When I try to check my k8s certs expiration states, I run the following command:

```sh
kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration
```

which ended up with:

```
name: Invalid value: "alpha_53_116": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
```

I was wondering why it needs to check the node's hostname? As the hostname of my master node couldn't be altered, is there any way to solve this problem?

---

complement:

OS: Centos 7.4
kubeadm version: 1.15.0

Comment: Could you provide your OS versiom, kubeadm and kubernetes version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed in your question, problem is with your node name.
According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#check-certificate-expiration) command `kubeadm alpha certs`

> The command shows expiration/residual time for the client certificates
>   in the /etc/kubernetes/pki folder and for the client certificate
>   embedded in the KUBECONFIG files used by kubeadm (admin.conf,
>   controller-manager.conf and scheduler.conf).

Mentioned files can be found in `/etc/kubernetes`. You can also check kubeadm init configuration using `kubeadm config print init-defaults`.

Those files will contain name of your hostname which is invalid in kubeadm/kubernetes. 
In short, as `kubeadm alpha certs` is based on KUBECONFIG files and pki folder, it will not go trought validation due to "_" sign. 
Unfortunately it is syntax issue so there is no workaround.

Please keep in mind that `alpha` is Kubeadm experimental sub-commands. So it might be changed in the future.